# SortedSet and SortedList fails with different enums

Tags: c#, session, sorting, enums

The whole story; I have some KeyValuePairs that I need to store in a session and my primary goal is to keep it small. Therefore I don't have the option of using many different collection. While the key is a different enum value of of a different enum type the value is always just a enum value of the same enum type. I have chosen a HashTable for this approach which content look like this (just many more):

```
// The Key-Value-Pairs
{ EnumTypA.ValueA1, MyEnum.ValueA },
{ EnumTypB.ValueB1, MyEnum.ValueB },
{ EnumTypC.ValueC1, MyEnum.ValueA },
{ EnumTypA.ValueA2, MyEnum.ValueC },
{ EnumTypB.ValueB1, MyEnum.ValueC }
```

At most I am running contains on that HashTable but for sure I also need to fetch the value at some point and I need to loop through all elements. That all works fine but now I have a new requirement to keep the order I have added them to the HashTable -> **BANG**

A HashTable is a map and that is not possible!

Now I thought about using a `SortedList<object, MyEnum>` or to go with more Data but slightly faster lookups and use a `SortedSet<object>` in addition to the HashTable.

*Content below has been edited*

The SortedList is implemented as

```
SortedList<Enum, MyEnum> mySortedList = new SortedList<Enum, MyEnum>();
```

the SortedSet is implemented as

```
SortedSet<Enum> mySortedSet = new SortedSet<Enum>();
```

The described Key - Value - Pairs are added to the sorted list with

```
void AddPair(Enum key, MyEnum value)
{
    mySortedList.Add(key, value);
}
```

And for the SortedSett like this

```
void AddPair(Enum key)
{
    mySortedSet.Add(key);
}
```

Both are failing with the exception:

> ***Object must be the same type as the
>   enum***

*My question is:* What goes wrong and how can I archive my goal?

> ***Used Solution***
>
> <strike>I've decided to life with the downside
>   of redundant data against slower
>   lookups and decided to implement a
>   `List<Enum>` which will retain the
>   insert order parallel to my already
>   existing HashTable.</strike>
>
> In my case I just have about 50-150
>   Elements so I decided to benchmark the
>   `Hashtable` against the
>   `List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>`
>
> Therefore I have create me the
>   following helper to implement
>   `ContainsKey()` to the
>   `List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>`

```
static bool ContainsKey(this List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> list, object key)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> p in list)
    {
        if (p.Key.Equals(key))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> I inserted the same 100 Entries and
>   checked randomly for one of ten
>   different entries in a 300000 loop.
>   And... the difference was tiny so I
>   decided to go with the
>   `List<KeyValuePair<object,object>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should store your data in an instance of `List<KeyValuePair<Enum, MyEnum>>` or `Dictionary<Enum, MyEnum>`.

`SortedSet` and `SortedList` are generic, but your keys are EnumTypeA/EnumTypeB, you need to specify the generic T with their base class(System.Enum) like:

```
SortedList<Enum, MyEnum> sorted = new SortedList<Enum, MyEnum>();
```

**EDIT**

> Why you got this exception

`SortedList` and `SortedSet` use a comparer inside to check if two keys are equal. `Comparer<Enum>.Default` will be used as the comparer if you didn't specify the comparer in the constructor. Unfortunately `Comparer<Enum>.Default` isn't implemented as you expected. It throws the exception if the two enums are not the same type.

> How to resolve the problem

If you don't want to use a `List<KeyValuePair<Enum, MyEnum>>` and insist using `SortedLIst`, you need to specify a comparer to the constructor like this:

```
class EnumComparer : IComparer<Enum>
{
    public int Compare(Enum x, Enum y)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode() - y.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var sorted = new SortedList<Enum, MyEnum>(new EnumComparer());
```

Btw, I think you need to obtain the "inserting order"? If so, `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` is a better choice, because `SortedSet` will prevent duplicated items.

Comment: @Danny to change the `SortedList` or `SortedSet` that way does not change the error. And does a dictionary or list obtain the insert order?

Comment: How are you using SortList/SortedSet? You need to provide some code. And what's the "error"? An exception? What's the message?

Comment: @Danny it's explained in the question; The exception says ***Object must be the same type as the enum*** I though the usage should be obvious but I will add some code right after this comment

Comment: @sra: Which line throws the exception when running?

Comment: @Danny `mySortedList.Add(key, value);` and `mySortedSet.Add(key);` It seems happens when I insert the first Key of another Enum Type

Comment: @sra: I think you can change `SortedList`/`SortedSet` to `List<KeyValuePair<Enum, MyEnum>>`, which obtains the insert order.

Comment: @sra: `SortedList`/`SortedSet` brings you trouble with the comparer of enum. `List` is ok in this case, and easy to use.

Comment: @Danny OK, but how can I do look-ups for the Key? Maybe I am totally wrong, but it seems to they are really complicated? But please correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: "Unfortunately Comparer<Enum>.Default isn't implemented wisely. It throws the exception if the two enums are not the same type." Why do you call this unwise? I can think of no better behavior since there is no reasonable way to order different types.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You are correct. I mean, the comparer isn't implemented as he expected. I've edited.

Comment: Your comparer is incorrect. It needs a insertion timestamp, and not based on the enum's value. Create a wrapper class eg `{ Enum, DateTime }`.

Comment: @Danny perfect answer! To bring a little light into this: There can be and there should be no duplicates. I just don't use the List<KeyValuePair<Enum, MyEnum>> cause the key lookups seems to me much more complicated then with the HashTable. And statisticly I am doing about twenty lookups before I do one loop over all. But please correct me if I am wrong with this.

Comment: @leppie can you explain why I need to wrapped it up with a TimeStamp?

Comment: @sra: You are not sorting according to value, but according to the way you added them to the list. Hence it will require some form of timestamp. IMO, if the list is small, just use `List<KVPair<K,V>>`, then you dont need to worry about all this extra shit.

Comment: @leppie Absolutely. But I still don't get my Head around how to easy check if the key exists in the `List<KVPair<K,V>>`, cause that is required much more often than the loop through all. Or maybe I am looking at it much to complicated...?